# Spark-Scala RDD, group by count from array of array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm fairly new to Spark-Scala and just started to learn it by myself so please bear with me, I am using oracle virtual machine.

Here is my code,

```
val dataLines = sc.textFile("Data/client_jobs.csv")
val data = dataLines.map(_.split(";"))

val values = data.map(array => (array(0), array(1))
```

I can fetch data using spark-shell, and get the data in array of array format like this,

```
val data = Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array("c1",20)
                                ,Array("c2",102)
                                ,Array("c3",50)
                                ,Array("c4",80)
                                ,Array("c5",140)
                                ,Array("c6",2036), Array("c7",568))
```

As you can see from the code I have also mapped it but instead of giving me an output like this

> Array(("c1",20), ("c2",102), ("c3",50)...)

It gives me,

> MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at code1.scala:14

From the array of array or the normal array I need to fetch data and get the output like shown below,

> (below100, 3)

> (100 to 150, 2)

> (above150, 2)

Basically it is only counting the jobs within the range.

I know very little about Spark-Scala, so any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have RDD of tuples, category can be applied to each value, and then grouped:

```
val data = Array(("c1", 20),
  ("c2", 102),
  ("c3", 50),
  ("c4", 80),
  ("c5", 140),
  ("c6", 2036),
  ("c7", 568))

val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data)

rdd.map(tuple =>
  (
    if (tuple._2 < 100) {
      "below100"
    }
    else if (tuple._2 >= 100 && tuple._2 <= 150) {
      "100 to 150"
    }
    else "above150"
    , 1
  )
).reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

Result is:

```
(below100,3)
(above150,2)
(100 to 150,2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but It doesn't work, the error it gives is,

```
error: not found: value sparkContext
[ERROR]     val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(bankdata)
[ERROR]               ^
[ERROR] one error found

```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but It gives an error,

`
so, I tried a different method, I just extracted integer values and stored it in an array like this
Array(20, 102, 50, 80, 140, 2036, 568)

I tried,



`if (x < "500") {
          print("below100",x)
          }
          else if (x >= "501" && x <= "1500") {
          print("100 to 150",x)
          }
          else 
          print("above150",x)`

The O/P:(below100, 20) (below100, 50) (below100, 80)... How to count, can't figure out.

sorry for the lousy writing, fairly new to this platform, still trying to figure out .

Comment: Line "val rdd = sparkContext.parallelize(data)" is just example data, you can use own RDD.